# f(x) = x to the power of 1/3 is defined for all values of x. Is it differentiable at x=0?

Tags: calculus

[image]

This is one of the video lectures which I am watching on derivative. I am confused that why wasnt is evaluated using the Power Rule which will give the result as 1/3 * 1/(x^2/3)

Comment: The power rule indeed leads to the same conclusion, but you need to make sure that you can use it at $x=0$, which is a "special" point. Total safety if you compute the derivative from the definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your screen shot is using the true definition of "the derivative of $f$ at $0$".

The Power Rule is a consequence of that definition applied to power functions.

In both approaches, you find the derivative at $0$ is undefined, so they do not disagree with each other. In some sense the Power Rule could be eyed with skepticism here, since it is usually viewed as a theorem for use when a derivative *does* exist, as opposed to here at $0$ where it does not. By directly using the limit definition of the derivative, there is no possible concern about that issue.

Also there is the context of the video to consider. It may be a video that was intended for an audience which has not yet learned the Power Rule. (Perhaps you know enough about the context to rule that out though.)

Comment: Indeed there was a video on power rule after the derivative. While I was reviewing the previous lecture, this question came to my mind.

Answer (score 1):

The power rule is used to find the derivative at a variable location $x$.
$$f(x) = x^{1/3}$$
$$f'(x) = \frac{d}{dx} x^{1/3} = \frac{1/3}{x^{2/3}}$$
$$f'(0) = \frac{1/3}{0} = \text{undefined}$$
The formula shown (actually the definition) is used to find the derivative at a specific location $c$. In this case, $c=0$ .

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to use the power rule to evaluate that the function is not differentiable - it is much easier to see that it goes to infinity with the power rule

Comment: Yes, the power rule is easier to use, but it only works for certain functions, like $x^{1/3}$. I think they used the definition to show you how it would work with other functions, like $g(x) = x^2\sin(1/x)$.

Comment: This function $g$ is undefined at $x = 0$, but if we redefine $g(0) = 0$, then it's continuous and differentiable (but not continuously differentiable!) : $g'(0) = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x^2\sin(1/x)-0}{x-0} = \lim_{x\to 0} x\sin(1/x)$ . The sine function is bounded between $1$ and $-1$, regardless of how big $1/x$ is, so the product $x\sin(1/x)$ approaches $0$, and $g'(0) = 0$ . This result could not be gotten with any rule (product, power, chain). The derivative is discontinuous; $\lim_{x\to 0} g'(x)$ does not exist, yet $g'(0) = 0$ .

Answer (score 1):

Let us check if the power rule is always usable at $x=0$. Let $r$ be a rational number with an odd denominator.

$$\left.(x^r)'\right|_{x=0}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{h^r-0^r}h=\lim_{h\to0}h^{r-1}.$$

This limit is $0$ when $r>1$, $1$ when $r=1$ and does not exist when $r<1$.

Comparatively, $rx^{r-1}$ evaluated at $0$ is $0$ when $r>1$, undeterminate* of the form $0^0$ when $r=1$ and does not exist when $r<1$.

So, yes, they could have used it.

---

*Some could claim that *by definition*, $0^0=1$.